# Как подключить spring boot и mysql через docker?

Tags: mysql, docker, spring-boot, docker-compose, dockerfile

Всем привет! Никак не могу подключиться к базе, которая основана на mysql образе. Пишет The driver has not received any packets from the server. Connection refused.

Докерфайл:

```
FROM openjdk:17 as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY build/libs/userlist-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar userlist-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","userlist-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Докер-компоуз:

```
version: "3.7"
  services:
    api_service:
      build: .
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
      environment:
        SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/user_list?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
      depends_on:
        - db
    db:
      image: mysql:8.0
      ports:
        - 3307:3306
      restart: always
      volumes:
        - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: annaanna18
        MYSQL_DATABASE: user_list
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: annaanna18
    client:
      container_name: user-client
      image: front
      ports:
        - 3000:3000
```

Application.properties:

```
database.url=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/user_list?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
database.username=root
database.password=annaanna18
```

Comment: спасибо, буду знать

Comment: `3307:3306` — [наружу выставляете](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports) порт 3307, а обращаться пытаетесь к 3306.

Comment: Александр, Анна обращается к mysql серверу по имени сервиса, а внутри контейнера слушается порт 3306.